# SOGo use users name for identity from LDAP

Tags: debian, openldap

I would like to make SOGo use the users full name instead of the username as the identity.
User authentication is done via the pam-ldapd module through a remote server. But somehow I can't figure out, how to tell SOGo from which field in the user's LDAP entry it should get the name (as in mail settings -> IMAP-Accounts -> Identities -> Name), which would also be shown as the senders name to the receiver.

I was already able to figure out which entry to modify so the GDM3 greeter of a Debian 11 desktop installation would show the users name (it seems to use the first entry in the gecos entry), but SOGo still shows the username as the sender's identity. I already modified every entry (dn, objectClass, givenName, sn, uid, uidNumber, gidNumber, homeDirectory, loginShell, mail, description, userPassword, cn, gecos are present) that contained the username to show the user's name (except userName and homeDirectory of course) for my account but SOGo for some reason doesn't change what it's showing like GDM3 did. I even added a displayName entry, nothing.

Is anybody experienced in a setup similar to ours and knows how to tell SOGo to use like the cn entry or the first entry in gecos for the users identity? Help would be much appreciated.

Our full setup:
Debian 10.5
SOGo 5.0.1, together with Dovecot and Postfix
the authentication server is running slapd 2.4.47, also on Debian 10.5

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that a nightly build in the last days has either activated that feature or fixed a bug related to it. I don't know which version exactly included the change and I don't know which LDAP field is used for it (possibilities would be displayName, gecos and cn) but know it works as intended.